# Performing PHP/SQL queries on a server with no direct access

Tags: php, sql, informix, cisco

I am working on putting together a PHP page to do Informix SQL queries on a Cisco CallManager server that, for whatever bizarre reason, does not allow for direct access to its Call Detail Reports via unixodbc or PDO.  I can ssh to the server and run queries fine, but I need to find a way to do those queries remotely so that I can throw them up on a web page for authenticated users (authentication is via secure LDAP - this piece already works fine).  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: If you cannot connect to the database with PHP, then it will not be possible directly. If the queried data is *somewhat* static, you can write shell script on that server to run your queries and output the data to a text file or .json file and read that with PHP instead.

Comment: Thank you, cillosis.  I appreciate the input, pretty much what I thought but I was hoping someone had a better idea :(  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the database server via SSH, I assume that you have access to the necessary ports on the shell of the informix machine.

The fact that you are barred from using this ports remotely is most probably a setting on the informix server, not allowing remote connection.

The solution could be to use an SSH tunnel and map the local port on informix to a port on your PHP machine.

The informix server will see this as a local connection, if all my above assumptions are right

A howto on how to set up such a tunnel can be found e.g. here:
http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html

will be something like:
   ssh -f user@informixserver.com -L 9908:informixserver.com.com:9908 -N

The local post 9908 is than mapped to port 9908 on the informix machine

Note the the 'remote' address via that port will be the iformix server address you use to establish your tunnel with, so if the DB server really wants to see 127.0.0.1 only this will not work, but can be tweaked a lot

Note (if it works) that you need to set the ports for your DB host accordingly when configuring the connection in PHP)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with unixodbc or PDO, but I would not attempt to query the Call Manager db directy if I were you.

You don't want to be stressing the CPU of the server, It's probably better to leave that CPU manage mission critical tasks.

There is also the risk to be told by TAC (Cisco customer support) that you are in an unsupported scenario, should anything bad happen to the server (related or not to what your doing)

With Call Manager, you can export CDR to a remote *FTP/TFTP server*. I would the query that server. That's probably much safer.

Just a thoughts...